# Setting part of summary with different colour while using preferences

Tags: android, listpreference

I have a set of *listpreferences* which I am displaying in a PreferenceActivity screen. I would like to display *a part* of the text in the summary field with some formatting, say italics, or different colour.

What would be a good way to go about this?
I am using the following code to set the summary of a listpreference:

```
lp.setSummary(myText);
//E.g myText = "My name is SoAndSo";
//Required output : "My name is *SoAndSo* (in italics)
//                         or
//                  "My name is *SoAndSo* **(in green)**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the text output in html, using html tags.
Here's one way:

```
mBox = new TextView(context);
mBox.setText(Html.fromHtml("My name is <i>SoAndSo</i>" +  "<br />" + 
            "<small>" + description + "</small>" + "<br />" + 
            "<small>" + DateAdded + "</small>"));
```

For an unofficial list of tags supported by this method, refer to [this link](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)